# Grouping data in pandas by rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data with this structure:

```
id   month   val   
1    0        4
2    0        4
3    0        5
1    1        3
2    1        7
3    1        9
1    2        12
2    2        1
3    2        5
1    3        10
2    3        4
3    3        7
...
```

I want to get mean val for each id, grouped by two months. Expected result:

```
id   two_months    val   
1       0          3.5
2       0          5.5
3       0          7
1       1          11
2       1          2.5
3       1          6
```

What's the simplest way to do it using Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If months are consecutive integers starting by `0` use integer division by `2`:

```
df = df.groupby(['id',df['month'] // 2])['val'].mean().sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  month   val
0   1      0   3.5
1   2      0   5.5
2   3      0   7.0
3   1      1  11.0
4   2      1   2.5
5   3      1   6.0
```

Possible solution with convert to datetimes:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['month'].add(1), format='%m')
df = df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(freq='2MS')])['val'].mean().sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index()
print (df)
   id      month   val
0   1 1900-01-01   3.5
1   2 1900-01-01   5.5
2   3 1900-01-01   7.0
3   1 1900-03-01  11.0
4   2 1900-03-01   2.5
5   3 1900-03-01   6.0
```

Comment: very similair but i think `df.groupby(["id", (df.groupby("id")["month"].cumcount()) // 2])["val"].mean().sort_index(0,1)` would work too

Comment: It worked, thanks. I have one more question. What if I want to get rid of month column and have unique ids. So instead of val I want to have column val0 - for month 0, val1 - for month 1, etc.

Comment: @Atericralf - Do you think `df['month'] = pd.factorize(df['month'])[0]` ?

Comment: @jezrael not really. Instead of repeating IDs (1,2, 3, 1, 2, 3) I want to add columns for val for each month. So id 1 would have columns: id, val0, val1, and values 1, 3.5, 11

Comment: @Atericralf - I got it, need pivoting. Use `df.groupby(['id',df['month'] // 2])['val'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)`, right?